# Is it possible to specify the lifetime of async function's result?

Tags: rust, async-await, lifetime

We can write the following

```rust
fn foo<'a, 'b>(va: &'a (), vb: &'b ()) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = ()> + 'b {
    async {}
}
```

without using the `async` keyword. Can we do the same with the `async` keyword?

We usually write

```rust
async fn foo<'a, 'b>(va: &'a (), vb: &'b ()) {
    async {}
}
```

But there is no where I can put the output lifetime `'b`.

## An example provided by a commentator Kitsu

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1f44e9f59eee1e9c0ac1b0497656189d)

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn foo<'a, 'b>(va: &'a i32, vb: &'b RefCell<i32>) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = i32> + 'b {
    let mut t = vb.borrow_mut();
    *t += va;
    let x = *t;
    async move { x }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible, though it rather a guess

Comment: Can you please write the minimal real use case?The first example doesn't work  if `'a` and `'b` don't have any relation: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e9d61119d8738c850e12c4c6cbf570d5

Comment: [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1f44e9f59eee1e9c0ac1b0497656189d) can be an example

Comment: @Kitsu Thanks but what I meant is  in `async fn` the whole block is an async and `'a` and `'b` are valid in that block most probably these lifetimes are related or same. So you cannot define independent lifetimes for `async fn`s. IMHO for your example, this kind of computation can be done outside of async function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async fn` always automatically depends on all lifetimes from its arguments.

There's no syntax to change it, because there's no other possibility. That's because calling `async fn` doesn't run any code from the function body, but only stores function's arguments in the `Future` it returns. The future will later use the arguments when it's polled, so it's tied to all the lifetimes of all arguments.

Comment: "There's no syntax to change it"?